# Bootstrap confirmation box

Tags: bootstrap-4, confirmation

Bootstrap confirmation box works good. Here is the code.

```
<a href="#" data-id = "{{ salaire.getDate_debut()|date("d/m/Y") }}" data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Confirmer la suppression ?" data-singleton="true" data-popout="true" target="_self">confirmation</a>
```

Unfortunatly when page is reloaded (F5) or when you leave the page and come back, the box confirmation box does not appear anymore.

Note : recharging the element only causes the same thing.

Somebody knows why ?

Thank you